# I can not bind redirect::to() and routes together, it does not redirect

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Everything looks right to me. It's so simple, but I dont know. I've looked everywhere.

Problem: It doesn't redirect. It doesn't give error nothing happens.
        But when I enter the browser `http://site.dev/fail`
        it shows "fail" word on screen (so it works).

routes.php:

```
Route::post('getir' , 'Ahir\Ticket\Controllers\TicketController@postInsert'); 

Route::get('fail', function()   {  return 'fail';   });

Route::get('success', function()  {    return 'success';  });
```

---

**edit everything**

**Scenario:**
on `site.dev/` (homepage) I press submit that form has this.

```
form action="getir"  method="POST" role="form"
```

so button redirect me to

```
Route::post('getir' , 'Ahir\Ticket\Controllers\TicketController@postInsert');
```

so this `postInsert` is triggered below  at controller ticket.

controller ticket:

```
<?php namespace Ahir\Ticket\Controllers;

use BaseController, Input;
//use Ahir\Ticket\Repositories\TicketInterface;

use Ahir\Ticket\Adapters\AdapterInterface ;

class TicketController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(AdapterInterface $adapter) //TicketInterface $repository
    {   
        //$this->repository = $repository;
          $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }

    public function postInsert()
    {
        $this->adapter->postInsert();

    }
}
```

**then it comes here**

codes

```
public function postInsert()
{
    // create the validation rules ------------------------
    $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required',          
        'content' => 'required',
        );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        // i added here return vardump('fail'); it displays on screen. 
        // so i know that program comes here
        // but the redirect  below neither gives error nor redirect. 
        //nothing happens here. idk why!
        return  Redirect::to('fail')->withErrors($validator);

    } else {
        // validation successful ---------------------------

        $this->obj->insert([

            'title' => Input::get('title') ,
            'content' => Input::get('content')
            ]);

         //here DOESNT work too.
         return   Redirect::to('success');
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: redirect  at the code neither gives error nor redirect. 
    nothing happens here i dont get it !

Comment: Ok, but debugging is turned on, right?

Comment: yes yes. its turned on i got lots of errors before this

Comment: when i enter url by hand like this  http://site.dev/fail  it goes and shows me the word "fail". 

i narrowed it down to 
   return  Redirect::to('fail')->withErrors($validator); 
and this doesnt work too. 
    return   Redirect::to('success');

Comment: Ok... Are you using Firefox / Chrome developer tools? In Chrome, pres ctrl+shift+i, then go to the 'network' tab, make the request and watch what happens. What status codes / headers do you get? Also, what happens if you don't pass the errors?

Comment: Another idea: How do you perform the post? Keep in mind that you not only have to call the controller function but also return what is returned from that controller function.

Comment: you mean that Redirect::to('fail')->withErrors($validator);   $validator  this varible shount be empty, right?.

Comment: but   return Redirect::to('success');    this doesnt work too. that doesnt explain why success doesnt work , isnt it?

Comment: That's weird... Could you please show the view or the code from where you trigger the post? And what is the HTTP status code of the response? It says content-length is 23 - what is the content?

Comment: added everthing thank you man. you are really trying for a newbie like me

Comment: I think the problem is, as already suspected above, a missing `return` statement in the calling function. Try this: `return $this->adapter->postInsert();` Otherwise, you'll just get an empty response - it's not falsy, your code is also not falsy, it's just empty, because you just call a function that maybe returns something, but you are not returning it to the application.

Comment: that worked!!! thank you so much . you are best. how can you know such things like that i envy you . thank youu

Comment: hey how to put tick mark to your comment to show it SOLVED the problem

Comment: It's not possible to mark a comment as an answer. I've posted it as a real answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't return anything from the calling function.

Your application calls the `postInsert()` method on your ticket controller. This function calls another function which returns a `Redirect`.

But you don't pass that returned Redirect back to the application, so the `postInsert()` function just terminates without any output. The application doesn't know what happens within the `postInsert()` function, it just waits for something to be returned. And since nothing is returned, the HTTP response is simply empty. In order to pass that Redirect back to the application, you also have to return it from the calling function:

```
public function postInsert()
{
    return $this->adapter->postInsert();

}
```